# simple_form checkbox does not generate sibling span for checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, simple-form

I am using [simple form  simple_form (v: 3.2.1)](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) with `bootstrap` in my current rails application( other developer previously worked on this project).
For creating radio button from `collection` I use

```
 = f.input :default_ship,
          label: 'foo)',
          collection: default_ship_options(@company),
          as: :radio_buttons
```

That generate html like

```
<span class="radio radio radio"><label for="foo"><input class="radio_buttons required" required="required" aria-required="true" type="radio" value="company" name="purchasing_source[default_ship]" id="foo"><span></span>Test Shipping Address</label></span>
```

Look at here an empty span `<span></span>` is created that actually for showing checkbox.

My CSS code:

```
    .radio, .checkbox {
position: relative;
display: block;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.radio label, .checkbox label {
min-height: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-weight: normal;
cursor: pointer;
}

label input[type=checkbox], label input[type=radio] {
display: none;
}

label input[type=checkbox] + span, label input[type=radio] + span {
display: inline-block;
width: 1.4em;
height: 1.4em;
margin-right: 0.5em;
vertical-align: middle;
cursor: pointer;
border: 1px solid #AAA;
}
```

Now My problem is simple form does not create extra `span` for `checkbox` element that's why no check box is shown for checkbox. Generated Html for checkbox is

```
<span class="checkbox"><label for="manufacturer_currencies_fr"><input class="check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="fr" name="manufacturer[currencies][]" id="manufacturer_currencies_fr">Euro</label></span>
```

How can I generate extra `span` also for checkbox?
(I do not want to change my css because it already used many places)

It's seem to me that I have to do something at `simple_form_bootstrap.rb` but not sure. It can also be that previous developer may override some method but I have no idea where I can find that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of wrapping check_boxes. They are treated in the same way, so you can use 'options' parameter to pass the necessary data with key "collection_wrapper_tag". You can go into class "form_builder" of simple_form and find it by yourself.

```
= f.collection_check_boxes :tariffs, @form.tariffs, :first, :last, {checked: @form.selected_tariffs, collection_wrapper_tag: 'span'}
```

Answer (score -1):

Best solution I found was to overwrite the label_input method on simple form's BooleanInput.

Add the boolean_input file in app/inputs/boolean_input.rb:

```
class BooleanInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::BooleanInput

  def label_input(wrapper_options = nil)
    if options[:label] == false || inline_label?
      input(wrapper_options)
    elsif nested_boolean_style?
      html_options = label_html_options.dup
      html_options[:class] ||= []
      html_options[:class].push(boolean_label_class) if boolean_label_class

      merged_input_options = merge_wrapper_options(input_html_options, wrapper_options)

      build_hidden_field_for_checkbox +
          @builder.label(label_target, html_options) {
            template.content_tag( :div, class: 'switch-checkbox') {
                build_check_box_without_hidden_field(merged_input_options) +
                content_tag(:span, '', class:'slider round')
            } + label_text
          }
    else
      input(wrapper_options) + label(wrapper_options)
    end
  end


end
```

Notice that I only added the sibbling span in case there is a label not inline and with nested_boolean_style? = true. 
Most of the code in the method is copy pasted from the original in simple form.